# get region/city from ip

Tags: php, ip, ip-geolocation

how can I retrieve the region and the city from an ip?
I have found this service:
http://api.hostip.info/?ip=xyz.qwe.rty

But It doesn't give me accurate info like this:
http://www.ipaddresslocation.org/

Do you know some free service?
I need to retrieve this info with a php script, but I wouldn't install external library.

Thank you so much

Comment: If you want to use LOCAL DATABASE, then use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642598/detect-country-city-php-with-maxmind-geoip

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is my favourite:

[ipinfodb](http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php)

Comment: but it doesn't give me city info. I am writing from Italy and it doesn't give me city info.

Comment: @michele What do you mean? It gives you country, region, city, coordinates and more.

Comment: In my experience the city lookups are basically useless outside the US, e.g. the one above gives my city as one about 150 miles away.

Comment: @joakimdahlstrom I am trying to have returned city with a link like this: http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=####&ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx but it is soooo slow....

Comment: I would have something like groupon.com, or or at least the region.

Comment: @Tim Fountain It also has to do with you ISP. Sometimes they're hiding the geo information about their customers, or maybe you have an ISP that isn't located near you. I'm from a smaller city in Sweden and it gives me good results.

Comment: the free version is very, very poor and innacurate.

Comment: How can I get paid version, I am not getting Pricing link there in site. Please share the link.

Comment: Page not found.

Answer (score 36):

http://ipinfo.io, my service, gives you city, country and other related information about an IP:

```
$ curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8
{
  "ip": "8.8.8.8",
  "hostname": "google-public-dns-a.google.com",
  "loc": "37.385999999999996,-122.0838",
  "org": "AS15169 Google Inc.",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "CA",
  "country": "US",
  "phone": 650
}
```

Here's a PHP example:

```
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']"));
echo $details->city; // -> "Mountain View"
```

Comment: close but it was close really with my city. It was about a 2 hours difference.

Comment: Can i use in wordpress ? I will be support ?

Answer (score 20):

**Free Geolocation API** http://ip-api.com/docs/

You can get information about your ip-address, country, region, city, isp, organization.

Response formats and examples: XML, JSON, CSV, PHP.

Usage limits:
Our system will automatically ban any IP addresses doing over 240 requests per minute.

PHP Example

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
if($query && $query['status'] == 'success') {
echo 'My IP: '.$query['query'].', '.$query['isp'].', '.$query['org'].', '.$query ['country'].', '.$query['regionName'].', '.$query['city'].'!';
} else {
echo 'Unable to get location';
}
```

Comment: I run a website that will have hundreds of requests per hour, eventually more, is there a service you offer for unlimited requests?

Comment: Limit is ```150 requests/minute``` as of march, 2016. Not counting that, very nice multilingual geolocation service.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this.

> $tags =
>   get_meta_tags('http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=94.55.180.139');
>   print $tags['city'];  // city name

Comment: very poor and inaccurate

Comment: unfortunately every ip based location service is inaccurate.

Comment: for inacurate I mean that returns another city, when maxmind don't

Answer (score 1):

if you want to retrieve the city of an IP through http://www.ipaddresslocation.org/ you follow this tutorial: https://www.facebook.com/Websitedevelopar/posts/468049883274297
But you change the RegEx with this string:

```
/<i>([a-z\s]+)\:[<\/i>\s]+<b>(.*)<\/b>/im
```

BYE