# Is there anyway to get cityname except using ip in php?

Tags: php

Is there any way to get city name except using IP in php, The following link getting correct city name

http://www.whatismyip.com/

if i am using following GEOlocatio and others get by ip, I am in karachi using ptcl it show my location islamabad due to ptcl server in islambad.

Comment: Please check these two  link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350626/get-region-city-from-ip. http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-record-by-name.php. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

[MaxMind GeoIP is great.](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/) They have PHP API as well.

Comment: i am asking for visitor's location.

Comment: @AdnanKhan it gives you visitor's location. The only way to get location without asking for it is to use IP geolocation.